# Guidance: Implementing a 10 or 12 Band Equalizer using NAudio

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio, equalizer

I'm building a Music Player using NAudio.
At the Moment I'm stuck in a way to implement a 10 or 12 Band PArametric Equalizer.
I've been digging the NAudio Library; and I'm not sure if NAudio is capable of if at all.
Therefore; I'm asking for further guidance.

How could I implement an Equalizer on my Music Player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple multi-band equalizer example in the NAudio.Extras project. Take a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio.Extras/Equalizer.cs).

Comment: Greetings Mark; Thank you for the prompt reply. Comming from you it means a lot. Can't wait to try this.

Comment: I couldn't understand what EqualizerBands[] are.

private readonly EqualizerBand[] bands; 

The array is part of anything or we should declare it?